# Can I store enum as ordinal instead of string in JaVers?

Tags: javers

I use JaVers 6.10.0 in Spring Boot to store versions of this class:

```java
class AUserBusinessData {

  @Id
  @PropertyName("i")
  private Long id;

  @PropertyName("s")
  JHAEUserStatus status;

}

public enum JHAEUserStatus {
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE,
}
```

JaVers stores this in the `STATE` column of the `JV_SNAPSHOT` table as follows:

```
{
  "i": 1202,
  "s": "ACTIVE",
}
```

Is there a way for me to store the enum as an ordinal (i.e, `0` or `1` in this case) instead of a string (e.g. `"ACTIVE"`, as seen above)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option out-of-the-box. You can try to write custom [JSON Type Adapter](https://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/#json-type-adapters), one per each enum type.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll try that.